# Asp.net Core 2 - How to use ServiceLocator in Asp.net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, service-locator

My `Startup` is like this :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // code here 
    Bootstraper.Setup(services);
}
```

And my `Bootstraper` class is like this :

```
public static partial class Bootstraper
{
    // code here 
    public static IServiceCollection CurrentServiceCollection { get;set;}

    public static IServiceProvider CurrentServiceProvider
    {
        get { return CurrentServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider(); }
    }    

    public static void Setup(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        // code here 
        SetupLog();
        InitializeCulture();
        InitializeDbContexts();
        RegisterDataModelRepositories();
    }
```

and this is content of my `RegisterDataModelRepositories()`:

```
CurrentServiceCollection.AddTransient<IDefAccidentGroupRepository>(p => new DefAccidentGroupRepository(ApplicationMainContextId));
CurrentServiceCollection.AddTransient<IDefGenderRepository>(p => new DefGenderRepository(ApplicationMainContextId));
```

in short : I just want to be able to use Service Locator in my methods without resolving dependency in class constructor ... is there any way around it ....

Comment: well , I just like to use something like Service Locator  to resolve my services in methods and I really don't care if this Anti Pattern ... http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/ ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependency injection can also be done on a by action basis.

Referece [Dependency injection into controllers: Action Injection with FromServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection#action-injection-with-fromservices)

> Sometimes you don't need a service for more than one action within your controller. In this case, it may make sense to inject the service as a parameter to the action method. This is done by marking the parameter with the attribute `[FromServices]`

```
public IActionResult SomeAction([FromServices] IReportService reports) {
    //...use the report service for this action only

    return View();
}
```

Just make sure that the required services are registered with the service collection.

```
services.AddTransient<IDefAccidentGroupRepository>(p => new DefAccidentGroupRepository(ApplicationMainContextId));
services.AddTransient<IDefGenderRepository>(p => new DefGenderRepository(ApplicationMainContextId));
services.AddTransient<IReportService, ReportService>().
```

Answer (score -2):

well , thanks for your help ... 
There is a easier and better way for it , I just need to add another Service that use these repository and then resolve that service in my controller and let Asp.net Core 2.0 DI to solve the problem for me ...

```
public interface IActionService 
{
   IRepositoryA repA {get;set;}
   IRepositoryB repB { get;set;}

   DoTaskX();
   DoTaskY();
}
```

then in my ActionService :

```
public class ActionService : IActionService 
{
   public IRepositoryA repA {get;set;}
   public IRepositoryB repB { get;set;}

   public ActionService (IRepositoryA rep_a , IRepositoryB rep_b ) {
      repA = rep_a;
      repB = rep_b;
   }

   DoTaskX(){
    // do task using repository A and B
   }
}
```

then I register IActionService  in Startup.cs and resolve itin my ActionController and life become easier and code become cleaner ...

the solution was easy but I had to change my mindset to solve the problem  ...